# animate replacement (loop through array) of body

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-animate, intervals

I successfully looped through an array of slides and update the body html with them like this:

```
var slides = ['slide 1 content', 'slide 2 content', 'slide 3 content'];

function displaySlides(arr){
    $('body').html(arr[0]);
    var i = 1;
    setInterval(
        function(){
            $('body').html(arr[i]);
            i++;
            if(i >= slides.length) i = 0;
        },8000);
}
displaySlides(slides);
```

Now it would be great if i could fade one slide out and fade the next one in.. or in other words do some kind of animation between slides.
Anyone has an idea how to do this?

Thanks!

M.

EXTRA QUESTION

I would like to refresh my list of slides every hour for example (in the example I set it to 16 seconds). So I got the code below, and after 16s it reloads slide 1 for a split of a second but immediately continues with the slide which should have come after the last slide just before refresh. Why is this happening? I expected it to just restart at slide 1 (so only show slide 1 and 2). Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mWXz/3/) (notice: here you don't see slide1 appear for a split of a second).

```
function displaySlides(arr){
    $('body').html(arr[0]);
    var i = 1;
    setInterval(
        function(){
            $('body').html(arr[i]);
            i++;
            if(i >= arr.length) i = 0;
        },8000);
}

setInterval(function() {
    var slides = ['slide 1 content', 'slide 2 content', 'slide 3 content'];
    displaySlides(slides);
}, 16000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) to do it

```
var i = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    $('body').fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).html(arr[i]).fadeIn()
    });
    i++;
    if (i >= slides.length) i = 0;
}, 2000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KW6a5/)

Comment: Works great!
Apparently it's even better to put the i++ below the fadeIn(), as now it shows first slide twice at start (1 time only though).

Answer (score 0):

```
function(){
    $('body').hide('slow',
        function()
        {
            $('body').html(arr[i]);
            $('body').show('slow');
            i++;
            if(i >= slides.length) i = 0;
        }
    );
},8000);
```

This will just fade out the element with class `body`, change it's html content and then fade in the control.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution to the second problem to: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mWXz/6/)

Basically the interval needed to be cleared:

```
var si = null;

function displaySlides(arr){
    $('body').html(arr[0]);
    var i = 1;
    si = setInterval(
        function(){
            $('body').html(arr[i]);
            i++;
            if(i >= arr.length) i = 0;
        },2000);
}

setInterval(function() {
    var slides = ['slide 1 content', 'slide 2 content', 'slide 3 content', 'slide 4 content', 'slide 5 content', 'slide 6 content', 'slide 7 content', 'slide 8 content'];
    clearInterval(si);
    displaySlides(slides);
}, 5000);
```